# How to find volunteering works in Testing?

Tags: qa-developer

How to find volunteering works in Testing?
I am looking for volunteering works in either Manual or Automation Testing. I am a Salesforce Certified Administrator, ISTQB certified Tester. Could anyone please provide any information on the volunteering?

Comment: Why do you want to volunteer ? this will help us direct you

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is perhaps your biggest playground. Pick a project you are interested in and try to find some bugs in it, apart from testing, you can learn how to build or deploy a piece of software. People involved in these opensource projects will usually be more than happy that someone is actually using their product and cares enough to find some time to report bugs and possible new features to their Issue page.

Apart from GitHub, there're several sites for Testers where you can sing up and wait for testing tasks. I've tried a few, but it never worked for me, so I don't even remember the names of these sites now. But this very idea does exist and you can give it a try.

My personal experience is that apart from the above-mentioned GitHub projects, no testing volunteering worked for me, which actually proves nothing much :D But I still think, it's much easier to get a job as a Tester than find volunteering as a Tester.

Comment: Those are called crowd testing or Crowdsourced testing.
I wouldn't refer to "GitHub projects" as such, open source projects is a more appropriate name since they can be hosted anywhere. Many OS projects have or requires serious testing, for example [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html) is not hosted on git and have "the SQLite library consists of approximately 143.4 KSLOC of C code. (KSLOC means thousands of "Source Lines Of Code" or, in other words, lines of code excluding blank lines and comments.) By comparison, the project has 640 times as much test code and test scripts "

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to look at which software do you use.
Most of them have some instructions on how you can help with testing.

E.g., [LibreOffice has a great community of testers](https://www.libreoffice.org/community/qa/). If you like games, [0 A.D. has a good community too](https://play0ad.com/community/participate/).

Also, if you are looking to work with a particular technology, search for "[Techology] open source project" will open many options.

For instance, if you want to work with Ember, [doing such search](https://www.icicletech.com/blog/16-opensource-emberjs-projects-to-learn-from) may show you that [Discord](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) and